# CLR Hosting: get details of an exception

Tags: c++, clr

I am trying to call methods of the .NET assembly from C++ using CLR Hosting. In particular I call static methods using mscorlib::_Type::InvokeMember_3().
Everything works just fine, but the question is how to retrieve information about an exception which might occur inside the managed code?

When using COM, I have EXCEPINFO structure, which I pass to IDispatch::Invoke(). But with CLR Hosting I do not see such options.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried calling GetErrorInfo(), but IErrorInfo::GetDescription() returns no new information, just "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."